# edit existing google docs spreadsheet using R

Tags: r, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have heard and have been testing with the RGoogleDocs R package that lets you log into an account and view google docs as well as upload or delete them. I could take the route of creating a new document and then uploading it after destroying the old one, but I wanted a more elegant way.

I have used rgoogledocs for accessing my spreadsheet. When it comes time for editing I cannot change any values.

```
#this line returns the value in the worksheet in column 1 row 1
myworksheet[[1]][1,1]

#this command does nothing, but I would like to change the value to cow
myworksheet[[1]][1,1] = "cow"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the new `googlesheets` package. Example interaction to set cell A1 to "cow":

```
library(devtools)
install_github('jennybc/googlesheets')
library(googlesheets)

my_sheets <- list_sheets()
myworksheet <- register_ss("worksheetname")
edit_cells(myworksheet, ws = 1, input = "cow", anchor = "A1")
```

Comment: Funny thing is, after searching for days I finally stumbled on this before I read your answer haha. I guess that is the way to go, thank you.

Comment: I keep getting an error when trying to install gspreadr. I have R version 3.1.3 with the latest R studio. I have installed the dependencies but the error happens when it creates the vignettes.

Comment: nvm I added the false to the build vignettes parameter and it worked. install_github('jennybc/gspreadr',build_vignettes=FALSE)

Comment: That sometimes happens with new packages when installing from GitHub. Glad it worked out!

Comment: haha im more used to installing with the r install command. Also quick question. I am getting the message 'data_frame' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr' when I try to do anything with gspreadr. I have dplyr but I need it for my shiny app, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Update dplyr! The latest CRAN version adds a convenience function called data_frame.

Comment: XD this helped a lot. Also sorry for asking one more question but when i try editing the cell i get Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '.' not found

Comment: That error is coming from dplyr and means that it isn't finding the first argument passed to some function inside a dplyr chain. Hard to debug without a lot more information.

Comment: I fixed the problem by deleting some saved r workbook files in my app folder. I get a new error however even when I try to run the examples from the gspreadr github examples. The error is Error: x <= letter_to_num("ZZ") are not all TRUE
In addition: Warning message:
In function_list[[i]](value) : NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73946/discussion-between-bacondoggie-and-ajar).